# order by date format custom field in cpt

Tags: wordpress, date, custom-post-type, custom-fields, meta-query

I have a cpt `proposta_gite` and a custom field `data` with `j F` date format

I would like to order my post by custom field `data` but this code won't work:

```
add_action( 'elementor/query/filter', function( $query ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_value', date( 'j F' ) );
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'data' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'proposta_gite' ] );
} );
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Are you just not getting the result order by date or is there any other issue we well?

Comment: Cpt —> custom post type!

Comment: I get no results! But if I leave only post type set everything is ok...

Comment: I recommend you always tag your question according to the tool or language you are using. I believe that this is the best way to attract those who know about it to your question.

Comment: anyone can help me please?